# Does accepting an answer make other people slightly less likely to respond?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is accepting an answer discouraging more answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18573/is-accepting-an-answer-discouraging-more-answers)

I know that it depends on a case-by-case basis. But I'm just wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I depends on what type of question it is.  If you question is, "How do I iterate through this list?" and you accept and answer people will most likely not place any more answers.  If you question is, "Using LINQ what is the most efficient way to iterate through a list?" you may get more answers because people feel that they have a better answer then the accepted answer. This is the same for an answer that is more open ended then "I need help with this" type of question.

Answer (score 4):

Dunno about other people, but when I have a better answer I provide it.  There's always a chance OP will change their selection.

Also, I think you tend to get more ambient rep in cases like this, as people see that the selected answer pales in comparison to my glorious winged answer.  Which often radiates a golden aura, and sometimes can cure urinary tract infections.  The color of the aura is just a coincidence, btw.

Comment: I detect no ego  ;)

Answer (score 3):

I guess it does : if you mark an answer as accepted, it means your problem is solved -- so there is no need to add an answer.

Except in some cases, of course, when the accepted answer is not that good ; but even then, I'd rather add comments to help the accepted answer be improved by its author *(as it's the answer that is most likely be the one people coming from search engines will read)*.

Answer (score 1):

In most of the cases this will deter other users from answering unless they know that the accepted answer is just wrong.

If you want/need more answers, I would suggest for you to delay the acceptance of an answer.