# Should Answered Questions be Appended with Accepted Answers?

Tags: discussion, multiple-answers

Should questions, especially one with many possible answers, be edited to include a section at the end detailing what the asker has learned or what progress has been made? I'm thinking of something related to the title text of [XKCD #979](http://xkcd.com/979/).

For instance, [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters) has a great list of the ten best answers to his question.

On the other hand,  [Shell command to sum integers, one per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/shell-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line) has no such list, but many valid answers. One commenter even pointed out that the question has potential. The question would, I believe, be much more useful to readers if he didn't have to dig through all the answers to find one that worked best for him.

Now, I understand that this is really [is the point of accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/181088), but I also wonder if for questions with multiple valid answers, [accepting an answer crowds out other answers or makes them appear invalid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18573/is-accepting-an-answer-discouraging-more-answers).

Comment: There's nothing stopping the OP from answering their own question in the manner you describe, and many do.

Answer (score 7):

No.

The accepted answer always (except when it's a self answer) comes straight after the question - regardless of the sort order.